# How to keep multiple machines synced with South and Git

Tags: python, django, git, django-south

So, although I enjoy South, I've had constant issues with this particular workflow:

- migrate a few times on machine A
- periodically push changes to Git
- after a long period, return to machine B
- pull from Git and migrations throw various errors for machine B

These errors are usually a "table already exists" errors.

Now I've read through numerous blog posts and stack questions, and frankly, there doesn't seem to be a clear answer on how to properly check in migration files (and whether you should at all) and how to really integrate South with Git.

What I'm looking for is a detailed run-through of how to use Git and South properly together, and to show what the workflow would be like between two machines.

Currently, what I'm having to do, is after a while completely clear out the migration folders and start from scratch. This doesn't seem like a good way to handle things.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to know where the doubt has arisen about committing South migration files. I certainly wasn't aware of any suggestion that you wouldn't.

With your workflow you don't specify whether the machines A and B are using the same or different databases. If your code is going to be significantly different between the two machines then they should use different databases. If the database schema gets ahead of the code then you will get errors. Obviously the schema cannot get behind the code because you should always run `migrate` after a code update.

My workflow is as follows:

```
A: create schema migrations and apply as they are created.
A: add schema migration files to subversion and commit
B: svn up
B: python manage.py migrate
B: continue coding!
```

Because migration files can contain code that translates data in the database you shouldn't delete the migrations because you will lose that code. I have a three person development team who have created 80+ migrations and not encountered any problems of the form you describe.

Comment: I had the same Problem `table already exists` when introducing south to my project at first. Even with the migrations and everything pulled from the repo. south promted me to drop the databases belonging to the managed model when I ran `migrate <app>`.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

with south and team workflow appears when two persons create migration without syncing to each other.

Imagine that we have some repo. Persons A and B clone it, then change some model, create migration and then push this all back. We will have 2 migrations with same number in the repo.

South will complain if you'll try to make migration with such history.

```
Inconsistent migration history
The following options are available:
   --merge: will just attempt the migration ignoring any potential dependency conflicts.
```

As stated in south docs http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part5.html you could try to use --merge option and south will try to merge migrations. It will fail if conflicting migrations changed same model(s).

```
./manage.py schemamigration --auto --merge appname
```

So the main rule for team is: at one time only one developer could change one model. If somebody started to change model then nobody should touch it until they have migration files up to date.

### Rules for team workflow with south and multiple git branches:

1. Before making changes in model double check if somebody already making changes there
2. Notify other members about you changes asap
3. Sync your migrations directories asap

Also from south docs:
when you pull in someone else’s model changes complete with their own migration, you’ll need to make a new empty migration that has the changes from both branches of development frozen in (if you’ve used mercurial, this is equivalent to a merge commit). To do so, simply run:

```
 ./manage.py schemamigration --empty appname merge_models
```

merge_models there is only new migration name

### Rules for team workflow with south and single git branch:

If all your team members commit to single branch, then best strategy will be to make model changes first, make migration and push it as soon as possible. Then work on other code.

This articles could also be interesting for you:

http://andrewingram.net/2012/dec/common-pitfalls-django-south/
http://anthony-tresontani.github.io/Django/2013/03/15/south-workflow/